# Generate specific combination in c# which create my expected output

Tags: c#

I have two Lists having multiple data in each list. And need below output which would be combination values of list(s).

```
Example1:
List1: {"A","B","C"}
List2: {"D","E"}

Expected Output Combinations:
{"A"}
{"B"}
{"C"}
{"D"}
{"E"}
{"A,D"}
{"A,E"} 
{"B,D"}
{"B,E"}
{"C,D"}
{"C,E"}

Example2:
List1: {"A","B"}
List2: {"D"}

Expected Output Combinations:
{"A"}
{"B"}
{"D"}
{"A,D"}
{"B,D"}
```

Here is code snippet which I am trying:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n)
{
    if (n == 0) yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();

    int count = 1; 
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        foreach (var innerSequence in source.Skip(count).Combinations(n - 1)) 
        {
            yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(innerSequence);}count++;
        } 
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IList<T> source)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> output = Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        output = output.Concat(source.Combinations(i));
    }
    return output;
}
```

...

```
List<string> lstCodes = new List<string>();
List<string> lstCodeOut = new List<string>();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox1.Text))
    lstCodes.AddRange(txtbo‌​x1.Text.Split(',').T‌​oList());
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox2.Text))
    lstCodes.AddRange(txtbo‌​x2.Text.Split(',').T‌​oList());
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox3.Text))
    lstCodes.AddRange(txtbo‌​x3.Text.Split(',').T‌​oList());

foreach (var sequence in lstCodes.AllCombinations())
{
    lstCodeOut.Add(string.Join(",", sequence));
}
txtBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstCodeOut);
```

Comment: You can start with a `for` loop or a `foreach`, later try some LINQ. What do you have so far and where did you get stuck? Note that StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service.

Comment: Learn basics before ask.

Comment: Here is code snippet which I am trying

Comment: Here is code snippet which I am tryingpublic static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int n) { if (n == 0)
            yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();int count = 1; foreach (T item in source){foreach (var innerSequence in source.Skip(count).Combinations(n - 1)) { yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(innerSequence);}count++; } }

Comment: public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> AllCombinations<T>(this IList<T> source) { IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> output = Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>(); for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++){ output = output.Concat(source.Combinations(i));} return output;
        }

Comment: List<string> lstCodes = new List<string>(); List<string> lstCodeOut = new List<string>();if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox1.Text))lstCodes.AddRange(txtbox1.Text.Split(',').ToList());if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox2.Text))lstCodes.AddRange(txtbox2.Text.Split(',').ToList());
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox3.Text))lstCodes.AddRange(txtbox3.Text.Split(',').ToList());foreach (var sequence in lstCodes.AllCombinations())
            {
                lstCodeOut.Add(string.Join(",", sequence));
            }
            txtBox.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstCodeOut);

Comment: @René Vogt, Luca Mazzanti : thanks!

Comment: @Ambi please use the [edit] button and post that code in your question instead of comments. This will be far more readable and your question will probably be reopened.

Comment: @Ambi and don't forget to tell what's wrong with your code so far (what how its results differ from what you expect).

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward path is to use basic foreach loops; this assumes no duplicates:

```
var l1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var l2 = new List<string> { "D", "E" };

var result = new HashSet<string>();

foreach( string s1 in l1 )
{
    result.Add( s1 );

    foreach( string s2 in l2 )
    {
        result.Add( s2 );
        result.Add( $"{s1},{s2}" );
    }
}
```

From here, we can refactor to remove some of the redundancy in the inner loop by concatenating the 2 lists then merging the 2 into the combinations:

```
var l1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var l2 = new List<string> { "D", "E" };

var result = new List<string>( l1.Concat( l2 ) );

foreach( string s1 in l1 )
{
    foreach( string s2 in l2 )
    {
        result.Add( $"{s1},{s2}" );
    }
}
```

And from here, we can refactor again into a LINQ statement:

```
var l1 = new List<string> { "A", "B", "C" };
var l2 = new List<string> { "D", "E" };

string[] result = l1
    .Concat( l2 )
    .Concat( l1.SelectMany( s1 => l2, ( s1, s2 ) => $"{s1},{s2}" ) )
    .ToArray();
```